# Getting ostream template to print instance attributes in list of pointers

Tags: c++, list, iterator, ostream

I'm trying to use a template function to print the attributes of the objects that are pointed to in my list.

```
class SomeClass {
  public:
   double myVal;
   int myID;
}

std::list< boost::shared_ptr< SomeClass > > myListOfPtrs;
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
  boost::shared_ptr< SomeClass > classPtr( new SomeClass );
  myListOfPtrs.push_back( classPtr );
}

template < typename T > void printList ( const std::list< T > &listRef ) {
  if ( listRef.empty() ) {
    cout << "List empty.";
  } else {
    std::ostream_iterator< T > output( cout, " " ); // How to reference myVal near here?
    std::copy( listRef.begin(), listRef.end(), output ); 
  }
}

printList( myListOfPtrs );
```

What's printing instead are the pointer addresses. I know what I'd normally do is something like `(*itr)->myVal`, but I'm not clear how to adapt the template function.

Comment: You're printing pointers, not objects. What did you expect to be printed?

Comment: I'm trying to print an attribute (such as `myVal`) of the thing pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use `shared_ptr` here. Your code doesn't give us any reason to use memory management:

```
std::list<SomeClass> myListofPtrs;
```

Then you need to provide your own implementation of the stream insertion operator for your class:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, SomeClass const& obj)
{
    return os << obj.myVal;
}
```

---

If you must use pointers then you can create your own loop:

```
for (auto a : myListOfPtrs)
{
    std::cout << (*a).myVal << " ";
}
```

Comment: I have to use `shared_ptr`. I've omitted the larger context. Unfortunately, `std::cout << (*iter).myVal << endl;` for `std::list< boost::shared_ptr<SomeClass> >::iterator iter = listRef.begin();....` in lieu of the template doesn't work either. I get `‘class boost::shared_ptr<SomeClass>’ has no member named ‘myVal’`

Comment: Needs to be `(*iter)->myVal`.

Comment: Yes, but this is with the explicit iterator. I've circumvented using the `ostream` iterator, which is what I was hoping to understand better.